# rust-ndarrayのdot()を用いるとリンクエラーが起きます

Tags: rust

動作環境:
Windows 10 home 64bit
rustc 1.26.2 stable
host x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

```
extern crate ndarray;
use ndarray::{arr2};

fn main() {
    let a = arr2(&[[1., 2.],[3., 4.]]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

こちらは`cargo run`で正常に動作するのですが、

```
extern crate ndarray;
use ndarray::{arr2};

fn main() {
    let a = arr2(&[[1., 2.],[3., 4.]]);
    let b = arr2(&[[1., 2.],[5., 6.]]);
    let matrix = a.dot(&b);
    println!("{:?}", matrix);
}
```

こちらでは `` linking with `C:\Program Files (x86)\~~~\x64\link.exe` failed: exit code: 1120 ``とリンクエラーが出てきます。
VC++のビルドツールなどは入れてるのですが。

調べても対処法などがわからなかったです。
解決方法などご存知の方いたら教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ここはstackoverflow 日本語版で stackoverflow.com とは別サイトなので本文は日本語で大丈夫です．リンクエラーが起こるときのコマンドも併記しとくと親切かもしれません

Comment: @meo さん、質問文下の「編集」から質問文を直せますので、そこから日本語に戻して頂くと幸いです。英語で質問したい場合、https://stackoverflow.com が使えます。ただし複数サイトに時間を置かず同時に質問することは[嫌われている](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)ため、どちらかでの質問に絞るのが良いと思います。

Comment: @Yosh さん、＠nettetsuuu さん。アドバイスありがとうございます。編集しておきました。

Comment: windows環境が無いので検証出来ないのですか、行列積ではBLASを使っているためいづれかのBLAS実装を選択する必要があるはずです。 https://github.com/bluss/ndarray/blob/master/README.rst#how-to-use-with-cargo の下側にあるblas-src等をdepencenciesに追加してみてください

Comment: @termoshtt さん。ご指摘通りdependenciesにblas-srcとopenblas-srcを追加すると解決しました！ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決した方法を回答として記述しておいてください。あと可能であればリンクエラーについてもう少し詳しく書いておいてくれませんか？

Comment: @termoshtt 回答およびリンクエラーの詳細追加しておきました。

Answer (score 5):

リンクエラー発生時のtomlファイルが

```
[dependencies]
ndarray = "0.11.0"
```

であったのを

```
[dependencies]
ndarray = { version = "0.11.0", feature = ["blas"] }
blas-src = { version = "0.2.0", default-features = false, features = ["openblas"] }
openblas-src = { version = "0.6.0", default-features = false, features = ["cblas", "system"] }
```

に変更することで解決しました。

なおリンクエラーの詳細は以下の通りです。
長いため一部省略しています

```
error: linking with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe` failed: exit code: 1120
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.14.26428\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib"
   "C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\sample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.10o4t5xq5v1kj9xh.rcgu.o"
                                    (略)
   "C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\sample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.ygdixdklmuroyow.rcgu.o" 
   "/OUT:C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\sample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.exe" 
   "C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\sample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.crate.allocator.rcgu.o" 
   "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" 
   "/NATVIS:C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" 
   "/NATVIS:C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" 
   "/LIBPATH:C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps" 
   "/LIBPATH:C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" 
   "C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\libndarray-ce30bc73040fb13c.rlib" 
                                    (略)
   "C:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\liblibc-8c2934cfe4982c42.rlib" 
   "C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-7448a93a40cf2c3f.rlib" 
                                    (略)
   "C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-e2f4c2f8ebed02cb.rlib" 
   "C:\\...\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-c4ca9f329f3bf160.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "shell32.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
  = note: Non-UTF-8 output: sample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.3ohv1ua84472yy1p.rcgu.o : error LNK2019:
    \x96\xa2\x89\xf0\x8c\x88\x82\xcc\x8aO\x95\x94\x83V\x83\x93\x83{\x83\x8b cblas_sgemm \x82\xaa\x8a\xd6\x90\x94 _ZN7ndarray6linalg11impl_linalg12mat_mul_impl17h358820cd8bf10458E 
    \x82\xc5\x8eQ\x8f\xc6\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xdc\x82\xb5\x82\xbd\x81B\r\nsample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.3ohv1ua84472yy1p.rcgu.o : error LNK2019:
    \x96\xa2\x89\xf0\x8c\x88\x82\xcc\x8aO\x95\x94\x83V\x83\x93\x83{\x83\x8b cblas_dgemm \x82\xaa\x8a\xd6\x90\x94 _ZN7ndarray6linalg11impl_linalg12mat_mul_impl17h358820cd8bf10458E
    \x82\xc5\x8eQ\x8f\xc6\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xdc\x82\xb5\x82\xbd\x81B\r\nC:\\...\\sample_proj\\target\\debug\\deps\\sample_proj-32a21e51ad011dc7.exe
: fatal error LNK1120: 2 \x8c\x8f\x82\xcc\x96\xa2\x89\xf0\x8c\x88\x82\xcc\x8aO\x95\x94\x8eQ\x8f\xc6\r\n
```